# How to make a div visible when user presses a certain key

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can't think of how to do this, I wan't a div element to unhide itself when the user presses a key on the keyboard, like instead of hovering a button or something.

Is this possible? thinking jquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).keypress(function(ev) {
    if (ev.which === 65 || ev.which === 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
         $('#mydiv').toggle();
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/R4rWn/

If you wanted to capture a control key (ctrl, alt, caps-lock, etc) then you have to use `.keydown()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind("keypress", function(e){
 if(e.which == <YOUR_KEY_CODE>) { 
   //Do something
 }
});
```

Check [this](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx) link to get a list of the keycode values.